# Can I create something like this in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

tag `<i>` inside the tag `<a>`

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> Profile</a>
```

how to make it in MVC @Html.ActionLink ?

Comment: Short answer is no. You would need to create you own HtmlHelper extension method.

Comment: I suppose you can't do it. The anly way is to create your own `HtmlHelper`. But on the other side why you heed this? HtmlHelpers really usefull for binding and when you heed only href - it's ok to use html.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find hov to do it with @Html.ActionLink , but I found ho to do it with @Url.Action:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("action","controller")"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> Profile</a>
```